# Form field (default text) + some more text

Tags: javascript, php, forms

I have a form field with default text, but my users have to paste a filename after this default text. How can I achieve that?

```
/td><th width="200px">VideoLink</th><td><input type="text" id="VideoLink" name="VideoLink" value="<?php echo $video_rec['VideoLink']; ?>"></input></td>

$video_rec['VideoLink'] = "rtmp://test123.cloudfront.net/cfx/st/mp4:";
```

My user has to paste the filename in that form field, but when the form is submitted that field should contain rtmp-url + filename (test.mp4)
Sample = rtmp://test123.cloudfront.net/cfx/st/mp4:TEST.mp4

I did check this solution [How to keep some default text in the input field?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25306772/how-to-keep-some-default-text-in-the-input-field), but when i right click to paste it removes the default text.

Comment: why can't your user just send the filename?

Comment: Put your default text in label before text field and user defined text will be added to field. You also need to put default text in hidden field for server side processing. Append both values afterwards.

Comment: after posting concat it "rtmp://test123.cloudfront.net/cfx/st/mp4/".$_POST['VideoLink']
beware about security issue that check filename is secure 
and for frontend you can set a label for it

Comment: @ParkashKumar Can you send some demo code for that

Comment: @APS_dev, something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/p9yttr1b/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this:

**HTML:**

```
<input type="text" id="defaultLink" name="defaultLink" class="defaultLink" 
    value="rtmp://test123.cloudfront.net/cfx/st/mp4:" disabled />
<input type="text" id="videoLink" name="videoLink" />
<input type="hidden" id="completeLink" name="completeLink" />

<input type="button" onclick="appendLink();" value="Append" />
```

**CSS:**

```
.defaultLink {
    min-width: 235px;
    border: none;
    background-color: transparent;
}
```

**JS:**

```
function appendLink(){
    var defaultLink = document.getElementById('defaultLink').value;
    var videoLink = document.getElementById('videoLink').value;    
    var completeLink = defaultLink + videoLink;

    alert(completeLink);

    document.getElementById('completeLink').value = completeLink;

}
```

Then, you can get complete URL from completeLink request attribute / parameter.

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/p9yttr1b/)

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't trust your users to provide correct input, let them paste as they wish, you can guide them with a note or label, ex. *please include the "rtmp://" bit* but ultimately you should validate the input server side.

You can try this:

```
$string = 'rtmp://test123.cloudfront.net/cfx/st/mp4:TEST.mp4';

//$string = 'test123.cloudfront.net/cfx/st/mp4:TEST.mp4';

// make sure to also strip any leading or trailing whitespace using trim()
// you can also process the input string even further before testing the protocol

if (!stripos($string)){
    $url = 'rtmp://' . trim($string);
}
else{
    $url = trim($string);
}

print $url;
```